# localhost does not process php script correctly

Tags: php, mysql, wampserver

I am learning about databases and GUI to make database management more user friendly. I successfully downloaded wampserver (3.0) and mysql (5.7). To test if the php prints "Hello world" (see PHP script below).

---

Script (saved as name.php)

```
>?
echo "Hello world";
?<
```

---

My output in the browser is:

```
>?
echo "Hello world";
?<
```

---

Can someone give advise me on what the problem is, and how I can fix it?

Comment: It should look like <?php echo 'foo'; ?>

Comment: Please format your code, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks. The `mysql` seems unrelated here.

Answer (score 2):

PHP scripts start with a `<?php` and end with a `?>`:

```
<?php
  echo 'Hello, World!';
?>
```

As correctly pointed out in the comments, the `?>` a the end of a file is optional and should - in most cases - not be used.

This will also work:

```
<?php
  echo 'Hello, World!';
```

In PHP scripts where you don't mix PHP and HTML this is the way to go.

Comment: You should not use the closing `?>` This introduces new problems if you have any whitespace character after them.

Comment: Problem is still there. 
I removed the "?>" at the end, it prints

<?php
  echo 'Hello, World!';

Comment: How do you request the file? Do you use `localhost/name.php`? Is your wampserver running?

Answer (score -2):

If you want to work with your databases using a web GUI once you have installed WAMP you can open up any web browser (be it firefox or chrome or whatever) and in he address bar write `http://localhost/phpmyadmin` or simply `localhost/phpmyadmin` . If you did not set any password during setup for your database the default credentials are user 'root' and no password. Phpmyadmin is a very user friendly web GUI for managing mysql databases that comes with basic setups of wamp and xampp

Also if you want to verify if php was installed correctly from a console window you can type `php -i` which would display info aboout your current version/setup/extensions installed/etc.